# Multisite favicon.ico and Google's favicon API

Tags: dns, parent-child, favicon

Is there a way to tell Google's favicon API (http://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com) to pull a specific favicon.ico?

I have multiple sites on the same domain. When a link is added in the profile for my YouTube channel or in a Google Plus profile to one of my sites, it automatically displays the favicon associated with the root domain. From what I've been able to learn about it, the API will automatically look for the favicon in the root domain - but does anyone know if there is there a way to tell their API to look for the favicon.ico in the child domain?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use rewrite rules in your webserver to send the request to the appropriate file.  For instance, in Apache you'd use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com                                                                                                                                    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon.ico                                                                                                                                      
RewriteRule ^(.*) /favicon-example.ico [L]
```

Use the appropriate [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) directives to filter your sites appropriately.

When you say that you have "multiple sites on the same domain", do you mean that example.com/foo and example.com/bar are different sites?  If so, you should probably switch them to subdomains (foo.example.com and bar.example.com).